# How to run scheduled job

Tags: cmd

I am struggling to find a way to run a scheduled job that has a special datestamp into it's name.
The name always starts with `"OS_HOUSEKEEP_"`, followed by the datestamp - e.g.

```
OS_HOUSEKEEP_2018022616171014980.job
```

Also, no other jobs having `"OS_HOUSEKEEP_"` in their names are present on the machine.

Could someone advise easiest way to target it and run it once with <s>MS-DOS</s> command(s)?

In addition, I thought to list the current jobs with the following command:

```
 schtasks /query /v /fo LIST | findstr "OS_HOUSEKEEP_".
```

Unfortunately it only comes as a result and I am unable to cache it then to process it by sections (devided with space).
No other solutions has come to my mind..

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: thought to list the current jobs with the following command: schtasks /query /v /fo LIST | findstr "OS_HOUSEKEEP_". Unfortunately it only comes as a result and I am unable to cache it then to process it by sections (devided with space). 
No other solutions has come to my mind..

Comment: Please update the question with this information so it will be visible to anyone :)

Comment: Use `for /f` to capture output of a command: `for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %a in ('schtasks /query /v /fo csv^|find "Recovery-Check"') do @echo %a` (in batchfiles use `%%a` instead of `%a`). Does that help?

Comment: Thank you very much! It is really helpful! 
Now the output is "\OS_HOUSEKEEP_2018022616171014980.job" with brackets and \. Do you think if we can somehow remove them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('schtasks /query /v /fo csv^|find "OS_HOUSEKEEP_"') do set "task=%%~a"
set "task=%task:~1%"
echo taskname is:%task%.
```

the tilde in `%%~a` removes the quotes, the second `set` command removes the first character.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!